# What changed on my question by meta

Tags: support

[Active page](https://money.stackexchange.com/?tab=active) shows my [question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/150926/wash-sale-with-leveraged-etf) as edited, but I could not find what actually the [Bot](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) changed. How I could know, I was the author of the question.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers to your question have not been voted on. As such the system doesn't know whether they are any good or not.

The [Community Bot](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) [bumped your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-a-question-to-be-bumped) in order to encourage people to vote on the answers. You can see that if you check the [post's timeline](https://money.stackexchange.com/posts/150926/timeline)

Comment: FWIW, When you have a higher participation score, one of the things you eventually gain is the ability to see what was changed by an edit.